# AppleScript only runs on startup but stops running after some time

Tags: applescript

Im trying to write an AppleScript that opens checks if the battery is charging and opens AlDente if it true and closes the app if the battery is at a certain percentage or not charging:

```
on batteryStatusChanged()
    set isCharging to (do shell script "pmset -g batt | grep 'charging'") -- checks battery
    
    if isCharging contains "discharging" then -- if battery is decreasing
        closeApp("AlDente")
    else -- if battery is charing 
        openApp("AlDente")
    end if
    
    delay 10 -- change delay in seconds
    batteryStatusChanged()
end batteryStatusChanged

on openApp("AlDente")
    tell application "System Events"
        if not (exists process "AlDente") then
            tell application "AlDente" to activate
        end if
    end tell
end openApp

on closeApp("AlDente")
    tell application "System Events"
        if exists process "AlDente" then
            tell application "AlDente" to quit
        end if
    end tell
end closeApp

batteryStatusChanged()
```

the script works well on startup but stops working after sometime if I run it in the scrip editor I don't get any errors and it works well in it.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice here is to create an AppleScript application that can sit and run in the background. To do that, replace your last line — `batteryStatusChanged()` — with the following:

```
on run
    batteryStatusChanged()
end run

on idle
    batteryStatusChanged()
    return 300 -- check every 300 seconds, aka five minutes
end idle
```

Save the script as an application: i.e., open the 'Save' dialog, and look to the bottom to set the pull-down menu and checkboxes to look like so:

[image: save dialog settings for AppleScript editor]

...and save it. Then just add this created application to your login items — system preferences ☞ Users and Groups ☞ Login Items. You should be good to go.